# Accessing a single item in listview of android using http json requests

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, listview

I am following this tutorial and I have gotten the code to display a list view of contacts. However, I am having issues viewing a single instance. The class SingleContactActivity doesn't 
exist in the code or tutorial zip.

I cannot find any other examples or explanations, I am completely stuck. For instance, when I click on a contact I want it to bring me to a new page showing that contacts' information. Using eclipse I created a SingleContactActivity class just to make the code happy, so when a contact is clicked on nothing actually happens- it brings me to a blank page.
Does anyone have any resources or explanations on how to do this?

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Use same website list view tutorial, all detailed there

Comment: Show some code where is your problem

Comment: I was able to figure out code problems with the listview tutorial you recommended, turns out it was just nuances with eclipse. However, this doesn't help me with json parsing and http requests.